# Insert value into a table in a different database

Tags: sql-server, date

I want to convert a value from a char column to a date and update a table in a different database.

This is my current code:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE, [CRSE_SDTE], 112)
FROM    SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER 

UPDATE  DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.new_TarikhMulaPengajian
SET     new_TarikhMulaPengajian = SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.CRSE_SDTE
WHERE   DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.STUDENTN
```

**Output:**

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 3
>   Could not find server 'DMSTAG' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified.

If necessary, I can execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: I was not successful in understanding your problem. Why is it not successful? an error or incorrect output? please post sample data.

Comment: **@Nick.MCDermaid** already update the result. Maybe the mistake on my coding..

Comment: DMSTAG database exist in same server or another server?

Comment: @SunilNaudiyal: Same server.

Comment: problem with update stateemnt  check this   DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.new_TarikhMulaPengajian, what is TEMP_AKAUN_MARA?

Comment: @SunilNaudiyal: TEMP_AKAUN_MARA (table) & new_TarikhMulaPengajian (field)

Comment: --Use below Syntax for updating data 
UPDATE  dbName.dbo.tableName SET ColumnName=yourValue
WHERE YourCondition

Comment: @SunilNaudiyal: Already try. Error here -->Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 36 The multi-part identifier "SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.STUDENTN" could not be bound.

Comment: in SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.CRSE_SDTE ,what is SMBM_DBPELJ?,what is DBPELJ,what is MSTUMASTER?,what is CRSE_SDTE?

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax to update

```
UPDATE  t1 SET t1.ColumnName=t2.ColumnName
FROM  dbName2.dbo.tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN  dnName1.dbo.tbl2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: select try_convert (date,[CRSE_SDTE],112) 
FROM SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER
UPDATE DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA SET new_TarikhMulaPengajian = SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.CRSE_SDTE
FROM  SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER
INNER JOIN DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA ON DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN  = SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.STUDENTN
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS

**OUTPUT --> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
I think ther is no need for DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.new_TarikhMulaPengajian only(Table Name) DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA is enough.

```
    UPDATE   DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
    SET     new_TarikhMulaPengajian = SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.CRSE_SDTE
    WHERE   DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.STUDENTN = SMBM_DBPELJ.DBPELJ.MSTUMASTER.STUDENTN
```